# Boost coroutines with global yield

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine, boost-coroutine

Since my [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346217/replace-lambda-function-with-normal-function-boost) got flagged because I asked two questions in one I'm gonna be more specific.

I want to use the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) library for context switching within a single thread.
Therefore my plan is to use [coroutines](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine.html).
But ideally I do not want to change the tranfer parameters or the function type of an existing function.

Is there a way to declare yield as a global variable for each task? Then I would not have an additional transfer parameter.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/coroutine2/all.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::coroutines2;
void task1(coroutine<void>::push_type& yield);
void task2(coroutine<void>::push_type& yield);

coroutine<void>::pull_type coro1(task1);
coroutine<void>::pull_type coro2(task2);

void task2(coroutine<void>::push_type& yield) {
    cout << "> Start task2\n";
    yield();
    cout << "> Continue task2\n";
    yield();
    cout << "> Finish task2\n";

}

void task1(coroutine<void>::push_type& yield) {
    cout << "> Start task1\n";
    yield();
    cout << "> Continue task1\n";
    yield();
    cout << "> Finish task1\n";
}

int main(void) {
    coro1();
    coro2();
    coro1();
    coro2();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> Start task1
> Start task2
> Continue task1
> Continue task2
> Finish task1
> Finish task2
```

Note: I also looked in the source code, but I don't really understand the templates etc. (I'm a C++ beginner). Maybe someone already has experience with this topic and can help me.

Comment: Is there a reason you use boost-coroutine2 instead of coroutine-ts?

Comment: Not really. You mean the [boost coroutine-ts](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutines_ts.html) right? I'm really new to the topic and I saw that the boost coroutines are pretty common, but I will have a look at the coroutine-ts.

Comment: start with this example for an echo server with boost coroutine-ts. "https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server.cpp". Compile it and try to change something. Then try the thing you really want to do (small steps!) and if you have a problem post it here.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not what I need. My plan is to use a regular (existing) function as a coroutine (no additional transfer parameters or special function types). Therefore I want to declare yield as a global variable. Then I could use a regular function as a coroutine with calling `yield()` in it.